# Why does the fist print statement of b in the function print 5 and not 6?

Tags: c++

I'm confused. I would expect that the first print statement in the function would print 6 and not 5. Because a++ + c++ = (1+1) + (3+1) = (2+4 = 6).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    std::cout << "intitialisation b:"<< b << std::endl;
    int c = 3;
    {
        auto b = ++a + c++;
        std::cout << "increment b in function:" << b << std::endl;
        auto e = b;
        c += ++b;
        std::cout << "increment b in function:" << b << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "increment b out function:" << b << std::endl;
    int* p = &a;
    int* q = &b;
    std::cout <<"value pointer:" << *q << std::endl;
    ++(*q);
    std::cout <<"value pointer:" << *q << std::endl;
    *p += a++ + (*p)++;
}
 
intitialisation b:2
increment b in function:5
increment b in function:6
increment b out function:2
value pointer:2
value pointer:3
```

Nadine

Comment: `++a` returns value after incremening. `c++` returns value before incrementing.

Comment: Also, your code and your question text don't really match.

Comment: `the first print statement`  the __first__ prints `intitialisation b:2`

Comment: You posted the same code before and we already know that `*p += a++ + (*p)++;` does no good. Please consider to reduce your code to a [mcve] in case your question is only about `auto b = ++a + c++;`. You already got an answer that refers to the code as a whole, but I suppose the answerer would not be too upset if you changed your code

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the statement

```
*p += a++ + (*p)++;
```

is *undefined*. That's because you have simultaneous reads and writes to `a` (sometimes via the pointer) in an unsequenced step.

That means that the *entire program* is undefined, somewhat paradoxically perhaps, including any statements that, conceptually speaking, have already been ran prior to that one. And that includes the specific statement you're asking about!

Setting that aside, `++a` evaluates to the incremented value of `a`, `c++` evaluates to the unincremented value of `c`. So if there were no undefined constructs in your code, the output would be 2 + 3 which is 5.

Comment: is it really like that? I watched a video recently, admittedly half asleep, and my takeaway message was that there are points of observable behavior and when there is UB between two points of observable behavior then from there on the program has UB. Can you back it up somehow, to make it more convincing? Any reference?

Comment: Apart from the last sentence, you wrote this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64894751/8372853) already, in response to the same OP, with the same code, just a couple of hours ago, so it should be quite clear that the UB part of the code is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @cigien read it again. The answer says that UB is traveling back in time, which is correct, I am just not convinced that it travels back that far

Comment: @cigien: Ha was it the same OP? I didn't check that - I only have my UB hat on today. In many ways this one is more interesting (it has the whole previous-statement-is-therefore-ub thing), but I may well tin it to keep the site clean.

Comment: @idclev463035818: It travels right back to the first statement in `main()`. There's a *really* good question on this out in SO somewhere - I'll try to find it.

Comment: this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527401/undefined-behavior-causing-time-travel ?

Comment: I don't think the UB part of the code is relevant actually, and I think that can be edited out of the question instead.

Comment: @idclev463035818: I seem to recall seeing a better one. It's a pity that the great Kerrek SB no longer contributes.

Comment: @cigien its not relevant for the question, thats why I suggested OP to reduce the code to a [mcve]. (removed that comment after this answer was posted) But the UB is relevant for the code as a whole and all its output (if this question is correct, which is what I am trying to get convinced)

Comment: @Bathsheba a pity indeed. Don't worry, I'll try to find it myself. You triggered my curiosity thats already a lot ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818: If I'm waiting for some tests to run later this evening, I'll try to come up with some code where prior statements are optimised out by aggressive compilers due to future UB statements (on the basis that a compiler is allowed to assume there are no undefined statements).

Comment: @idclev463035818 Fair enough. Since the UB in the OP's code doesn't actually affect the behavior they're asking about, it feels like a red herring. But you're right, it's up to the OP to decide that.

Comment: There's some very fun examples [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehyHyAIa5so) including time travel effects :)

Comment: @cigien: But it might! A standards compliant compiler with optimisations turned up to the maximum may well generate `int main(){}`. As compilers get more and more aggressive, these things are starting to happen with code that contains UB.

Comment: Sure, I'm not disputing that it *could* affect the behavior, I'm just saying that it doesn't in this case. If the question is not edited, then it's just a dupe of the "undefined behavior and sequence points" target :(

Comment: @cigien I readded my comment, lets see what happens

Comment: @idclev463035818 • A former co-worker of mine wrote up a nice blog post on [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).  Undefined behavior is the stuff nightmares are made of.

Comment: @Eljay I know about the effect, but I haven't seen a conclusive example along the line of `int x = 0; /*some code all fine*/ std::cout << x; int y; std::cout << y;` yet. The second `cout` is UB no doubts, what guarantees do I get for the first? I know this is purely academical and maybe I am overthinking it, but ... you know... nightmares and all that, maybe it is a little less bad than this answer wants me to believe

Comment: @Eljay thanks for the article anyhow.